# FPDF Multicell to be displayed next to each other within a for and if statement

Tags: php, fpdf

With the code below I can display the Labels and Values next to each other, and this works fine.

```
 // New Contact Label
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, $addNewContactLabel,0,1);
$pdf->Ln(6);

// New Contact Value Width
$labels = $pdf->GetX();
$values = $pdf->GetY();
$AddNewContactLabelWidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($addNewContactLabel,'','B');
$pdf->SetXY($labels + $AddNewContactLabelWidth, $values);

// New Contact Value
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, $addNewContactValue,0,1);
$pdf->Ln(6);
```

**Results:**

```
Labels:Values

Labels:Values
```

Now when I put the same code in a "for" and "if" statement, I have the Values appearing a line below e.g.

```
// Add New Contact Label
for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++) {

$addNewContactLabel = (empty($_POST["addNewContactLabel_{$x}"])) ? '' : $_POST["addNewContactLabel_{$x}"];
$addNewContactValue = (empty($_POST["addNewContactValue_{$x}"])) ? '' : $_POST["addNewContactValue_{$x}"];

$ifAddNewContactLabel = "addNewContactLabel_{$x}";
$ifAddNewContactValue = "addNewContactValue_{$x}";


if ($ifAddNewContactLabel = $addNewContactLabel AND $ifAddNewContactValue = $addNewContactValue) {


 // New Contact Label
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, $addNewContactLabel,0,1);
$pdf->Ln(6);

// New Contact Value Width
$labels = $pdf->GetX();
$values = $pdf->GetY();
$AddNewContactLabelWidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($addNewContactLabel,'','B');
$pdf->SetXY($labels + $AddNewContactLabelWidth, $values);

// New Contact Value
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, $addNewContactValue,0,1);
$pdf->Ln(6);


}
}
```

**Results**

```
Labels:
       Values

Labels: 
       Values
```

While I want them to be displayed like in the first example e.g.

```
Labels:Values
Labels:Values
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to remove the line break $pdf->Ln(6); after New Contact Label.